# Fastest way to move data from Oracle to MS Access via VBScript

Tags: ms-access, vbscript, oracle11g, vba

Normally, I would just loop through using Recordset.AddNew, but this is painfully slow when dealing with large recordsets -- is there a better way to do it? I was hoping there would be a way to simply write an insert statement to go from Oracle to Access, perhaps by using two ADO connects, but the only examples I can find are in VB.net (using OleDbCommand), which is sadly not an option. Is this simply a limitation of VBScript?

Thanks!

Comment: oof - first of all you're going the wrong way :) - you shuold be able to connect directly from access to Oracle as a remote database - then just issue a SQL insert statement - like INSERT INTO mytable as select from yourtable.

Comment: Thanks! I have thought about doing this, but have avoided it for a few reasons (and now I am going to need to highlight the stupidity of the problem) -- essentially, they want me to pull low-level data for ~230 locations and load them into individual access databases =/ The query itself is mostly the same -- only the location will change, so I thought there may be an easier way. And yes, I realize that the very fact that they want to do this is stupid and ridiculous. Do you think it still makes more sense to connected to Oracle from each of the instances of Access?

Comment: How about SELECT INTO against a connection in MS Access?

Answer (score 1):

Your question tags include access-vba, so I'll suggest the [DoCmd.TransferDatabase Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb214131%28office.12%29.aspx).

This example, near the bottom of the page, is to create an ODBC link to a SQL Server table.  It assumes a DSN (data source name) named `DataSource1`.  The link name in Access will be `Authors`, and the server source table is named `dboAuthors`.

```
DoCmd.TransferDatabase acLink, "ODBC Database", _
    "ODBC;DSN=DataSource1;UID=User2;PWD=www;LANGUAGE=us_english;" _
    & "DATABASE=pubs", acTable, "Authors", "dboAuthors"
```

You can adapt that for Oracle with an appropriate DSN.  And if you want to import rather than link, substitute `acImport` for `acLink`.

And actually, you might not even need code for this.  With a working DSN, you can import (or link) via the Access user interface.

Your title mentioned VBScript.  Tell us if you actually must use VBScript instead of VBA.

After reading your comments, I think you would be better of with a different approach.

Create a database with an ODBC link to the Oracle table.

Then export subsets of that table data to your individual database files.

```
SELECT master_link.* INTO local_table IN 'c:\somefolder\db1.mdb'
FROM master_link
WHERE location = 'location1';
```

Then adjust the SQL for each target db file and data selection criterion.  It should be easy to drive that from a simple VBA procedure.

Comment: Sorry -- I should have been more clear in my OP -- I can use VBA, I just felt that VBScript may be easier since I will need to deal with a large number of access databases. Maybe I could use the TransferDatabase method from an Access Application object in VBScript? MSDN also has a note that I could use ADO Recordset.ActiveConnection? I am just not sure what the best approach is.

Comment: I think the best approach is per Remou's comment.  I outlined it as an update to my answer.

Comment: That makes a lot of sense! Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Here are a few notes for VBScript using SQL Server, rather than Oracle, however, it should be possible to use something very similar.

```
Const CreatePath = "Z:\docs\"
Const Provider = "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;"
''The easiest way to get this line is from the connect property of 
''a linked table
Const ServerInLine = "[ODBC;DRIVER=SQL Server;SERVER=server;Trusted_Connection=Yes;DATABASE=db]"
''Change this to the Oracle connection
Const ServerConnect = "Provider=sqloledb;Data Source=server;Initial Catalog=db;Integrated Security=SSPI;"

Dim cnSS ''As ADODB.Connection
Dim cnMSA ''As ADODB.Connection
Dim cat ''As New ADOX.Catalog

Set cat = CreateObject("ADOX.Catalog")

Set cnSS = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
Set cnMSA = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
Set rs = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")

cnSS.Open ServerConnect

''Only the locations that exist. Assuming a location table
''with a description, Location
sSQL = "SELECT DISTINCT a.LocationID, b.Location FROM ATable a "
sSQL = sSQL & "INNER JOIN Location b ON a.LocationID = b.ID"

rs.Open sSQL, cnSS

Do While Not rs.EOF

    DBName = CreatePath & Trim(rs.Fields("Location")) & ".accdb"
    scn = "Provider=" & Provider & ";Data Source=" & DBName

    cat.Create scn

    cnMSA.Open scn

    sSQL = "SELECT * INTO " & Replace(Trim(rs.Fields("Location")), " ", "")
    sSQL = sSQL & " FROM " & ServerInLine & ".ATable"
    sSQL = sSQL & " WHERE LocationID=" & rs.Fields("LocationID")

    cnMSA.Execute sSQL, recs
    sMsg = sMsg & vbCrLf & DBName & " created " & recs

    rs.MoveNext
    cnMSA.Close
Loop

MsgBox sMsg
```